# Use NuGet or Bower in Visual Studio 2015 Cordova Template Project

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

When we create a visual studio 2015 cordova template project , the project have one "www" folder , if we use nuget or bower to install 3rd package (eg:winjs , jquery...) , the package not be put in "www" folder , the package will be put in project root .

How could we use nuget or bower  like web site project , the package will be put in www folder

Comment: I don't know about NuGet, but for bower packages you can use `wiredep` in a `gulp` task to copy dependancies automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I am using grunt for copying the files from Bower. This has the advantage that I have only the files in my app which I need really.